# Non-nilpotent group where the union of the upper central groups equals the whole group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, infinite-groups, nilpotent-groups

I am studying *residually nilpotent* groups. I am using the following defintions.

**Lower central series:** Let $G$ be a group. Then we inductively define the lower central series of $G$ as
$$\gamma_1(G) = G,\ \gamma_{i}(G) = [G,\gamma_{i-1}(G)]\ \forall i> 1.$$

**Nilpotent:** Let $G$ be a group. Then $G$ is said to be nilpotent if there exists an integer $c\geq 1$ such that $\gamma_c(G) = \{1\}$.

**Residually nilpotent:** Let $G$ be a group. Then we say that $G$ is residually nilpotent if
$$ \bigcap_{n\geq 1} \gamma_n(G) = \{1\}.$$

It's clear that every nilpotent group is also residually nilpotent. However, the converse does not hold. For example, if $\mathcal{D}_\infty$ is the infinite dihedral group, then one can show that $\mathcal{D}_\infty$ is residually nilpotent but not nilpotent.

My question is the following: can we define similar concepts surrounding the **upper** central series of a group $G$. This series is defined as follows:
$$ Z_0(G) = \{1\},\ \frac{Z_i(G)}{Z_{i-1}(G)} = Z\left(\frac{G}{Z_{i-1}(G)}\right)\ \forall i>0.$$

With the definition of residual nilpotency in mind, I was wondering if there exist **non-nilpotent** groups $G$ such that
$$ \bigcup_{n\geq 0} Z_n(G) = G.$$
I can't seem to find any example of such a group, but I don't know why it wouldn't be possible. Has this *counterpart* of residually nilpotent groups been studied somewhere? I did some research, but could not find anything concrete.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could take an infinite direct product of finite nilpotent groups $G_n$ of class $n$, such as dihedral groups of order $2^{n+1}$. Note that any such example has to be infinitely generated.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am momentarily focussing on finitely generated groups, so I wasn't thinking about infinitely generated examples.

Comment: @noparadise but if $G$ is finitely generated and is increasing union of a sequence of subgroups, then it equals one of these subgroups.  So if $G=\bigcup_n Z_n(g)$, then $G=Z_n(G)$ for some $n$, i.e., $G$ is nilpotent.